# Странное поведение при transform

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

Вот ссылка на код с работающим примером:
http://codepen.io/Bimbam/pen/rWPbpe

```
<ul class="cnap-items text-center">
  <li class="adm-tax">
     <p>Нажми на меня</p>
  </li>
```

Вопрос, почему блок не расширяется просто в правую сторону, а преимущественно расширяясь в парвую сторону, он немного расширяется в левую а потом возвращается назад ?
С помощью transform-origin выбрал координату 0% по иксу, 50% по игрику, с помощью scaleX растягиваю в правую сторону, но что-то всё получается не совсем так, как хотелось бы. А хотелось что-бы оно линейно,расширилось в правую сторону ...

Comment: http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/QGoLXg

Comment: @Elena Semenchenko О да ! Добавьте в правильные ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немножко поправила код:

```js
$(".adm-tax").click(function(event) {

 $(".adm-tax").css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'scaleX(2.1)',
     ' transform': 'scaleX(2.1)'
 });
 
});
```

```css
.cnap-items {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.cnap-items li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-align: center;
 width: 400px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #009852;
 margin-top: 10px;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-left: 3px solid #036136;
}
.adm-tax {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: all 5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cnap-items text-center">
 <li class="adm-tax"><p>Нажми на меня</p></li>
</ul>
```